# How to get the description or name from a release in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I have read through the documentation for Github actions and the release action, yet I can find nothing on how to get the name from the action. Do I need to run a fetch call or something else?

```
name: Publish to Bintray

on:
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:
    

jobs:
  publish:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Grant execute permission for gradlew
      run: chmod +x gradlew
    - name: Build with Gradle
      run: ./gradlew curseforge uploadSubProjects publishToModrinth --parallel --stacktrace
      env:
          BINTRAY_USER: oroarmor
          BINTRAY_KEY: ${{ secrets.BINTRAY_KEY }}
          CURSE_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.CURSE_API_KEY }}
          MODRINTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.MODRINTH_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: What's the trigger for your workflow? `release`, type `published`? If so, the name is in the `github.event` context, at `github.event.release.name`.

Comment: It is the release event.

Comment: Then it's at `github.event.release.name`, see [`release` event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#release) --> [release webhook payload](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#release) --> [release object](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release)

Comment: Notice that when you run it via `workflow_dispatch`, it's *not* there because that event doesn't know anything about a release.

Comment: Yeah, i only use that in rare cases, as i can change the name when i publish. Mostly just a convenience thing.

Comment: If you show how you want to use the name, I can add an answer that uses the context.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `github.event.release.name` and `github.event.release.body`:

```yaml
name: After Release

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  after-release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo "Name: ${{ github.event.release.name }} Description: ${{ github.event.release.body }}"
```